# $_SESSION changing when going to profile

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've made a login script that sets a username and token session when the user logs in, the problem is that if I go to the profile page right after I log in the sessions do not carry over, the only way to prevent this is by refreshing the index page after i've logged in which then sets the session. However as soon as I've logged in Krumo displays the session variables fine.

For some reason it doesn't register the session as being valid and displays the not logged in message. However if I refresh the index page (where I log in) before navigating to the profile page the session is valid and picked up.

**PICTURES**

---

- Right after I log in from the index page -

[image]

- The profile page if I navigate as
  soon as I log in

[image]

---

Furthermore, if I logout from the Profile page it should destroy the session and go back to the homepage. However when I arrive back to the homepage I find I have the previous sessions token.

There is quite a bit of code as I'm going it through a class.

To Summarize

- I log in from index page
- I navigate to profile page after login and no session is set.
- If i refresh the index page once after i log in the profile page does have a session set.
- While i have a valid session, if I try to logout from the profile page I get a token mismatch and the index page shows the the previous sessions token (this confuses me the most).
- ***If I log in from the index page, I can log out right away and it all works provided I don't go to the profile page and log out from there.***

CHANGES MADE TO POST

---

- I've added links to the pictures pictures.
- Moved fonts.html down away from session_start, problem persists.

---

PHP used in index.php file

**Index.php file:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/Krumo/class.krumo.php");
include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/class_loader.php");
    $sessCheck = new userFunc;
    if($sessCheck->validSess('bool')){
        $sess = true;
    }
    else{ $sess = false;}
    krumo($_SESSION);
include("style/fonts/fonts.html");
?>

<?php
$bar = new accountBar;
$bar->getBar($sess);        
?>
```

**My login.php file that gets the login form data posted to it:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/class_loader.php");
    $login = new login();
    if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Please fill out all the information";
        header("location:/");
    }
    $login = $login->startLogin($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
    header("location:/");

?>
```

**My Login form calls the login class which is:**

```
<?php
session_start();
class login{

    /**
        * startLogin()
        *   PARAMETERS: username, password
        *   RETURN: start login process
        *   DESCRIPTION: Start login process and handle login functions
        */
    function startLogin($u, $p){
        $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $u);
        $u = strtolower($u);
        $u = (trim($u));
        $p = (trim($p));
        if($u == "" || $p == ""){
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Please fill out all the information TEST";
            //header("location:/");
            return false;
        }
        $salt = $this->grabSalt($u);

        //echo "salt is: ".$salt."<br>";
        $p = md5($p.$salt);
        //echo "password is: ".$p."<br>";
        $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
        if($this->checkPswd($u, $p)){
        //  echo "Passwords Match!<br>";
            $this->setSessions($u);
        }
        else{
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Username or password is not correct";
            header("location:/");
        }
    }


    /**
        * grabSalt()
        *   PARAMETERS: username
        *   RETURN: salt for that user
        *   DESCRIPTION: Grab the users salt for use in password matching
        */
    function grabSalt($u){
        $conx = mysqli_connect("mysql.pipeten.co.uk", "********", "********", "******_GameAndShame");   
        $stmt = $conx->prepare("SELECT `UID` FROM users WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$u);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->bind_result($uid);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $conx->prepare("SELECT `salt` FROM users_salts WHERE `UID` = ? LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bind_param('i',$uid);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->bind_result($salt);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->close();
            }else{$stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
        }else{$stmt->error; $stmt->close();} //USER NOT FOUND IN DB 
        return $salt;
    }

    /**
        * checkPswd()
        *   PARAMETERS: $p (password), $u (username)
        *   RETURN: true of false
        *   DESCRIPTION: takes the username and hashed password and checks it against the user in the database, if it matches up we return true
        */
        function checkPswd($u, $p){
            $conx = mysqli_connect("mysql.pipeten.co.uk", "********", "********", "******_GameAndShame");   
            $stmt = $conx->prepare("SELECT `password` from users WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$u);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->bind_result($dbp);
                $stmt->fetch();
                //echo "dbpassword is: ".$dbp."<br>";
                if($dbp == $p){$stmt->close(); return true;}else{$stmt->close(); return false;}
            }else{$stmt->error; $stmt->close();}

        }



    /**
        * setSessions()
        *   PARAMETERS: $u (username)
        *   RETURN:
        *   DESCRIPTION: sets the user session for the person.
        */
        function setSessions($u){
            $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
            $t = md5($u.time());
            $conx = mysqli_connect("mysql.pipeten.co.uk", "********", "********", "******_GameAndShame");
            $stmt = $conx->prepare("UPDATE users SET `ip` = ?, `lastlogin` = NOW() WHERE `username` = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss",$ip,$u);
            if($stmt->execute()){ $stmt->close();}else{$stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
            $stmt = $conx->prepare("SELECT `token` from users_tokens WHERE `username` = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$u);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->bind_result($count);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->close();
                if($count != NULL){
                    $stmt = $conx->prepare("UPDATE users_tokens SET `token` = ?, `IP` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$t, $ip, $u);
                    if($stmt->execute()){$stmt->close();}else{$stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
                }
                else{
                    $stmt = $conx->prepare("INSERT INTO users_tokens (`username`, `token`, `IP`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$u, $t, $ip);
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                    }else{ $stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
                }
            }else{ $stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
        //  setcookie("u", $u, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "", "", "", TRUE);
        //  setcookie("t", $t, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "", "", "", TRUE);
            echo "SUCCESS";
            $_SESSION['t'] = $t;
            $_SESSION['u'] = $u;
            return;
        }


}
?>
```

**My userFunc class file:**

```
function validSess($a = 'bool'){
    $conx = mysqli_connect("mysql.pipeten.co.uk", "********", "********", "******_GameAndShame");
    if(isset($_SESSION['u']) && isset($_SESSION['t'])){
        $u = $_SESSION['u'];
        $t = $_SESSION['t'];
        $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $u);
        $t = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $t);
        $user_ok = $this->evalLoggedUser($conx,$u,$t);
        if($user_ok){
            if($a == 'bool'){
            return true;
            }
        }else{return false;}
    }
}

function evalLoggedUser($conx,$u,$t){
    $stmt = $conx->prepare("SELECT `ip` FROM users WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$u);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->bind_result($ip);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }else{$stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
    $stmt = $conx->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_tokens WHERE `username` = ? AND `IP` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$u,$ip);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->bind_result($uid, $user, $token, $ip2);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if($ip == $ip2){
            if($ip2 == preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))){
                if($t == $token){
                    return true;
                }else{ echo "Invalid Token, somebody else could have logged in as you?"; }
            }else{header("location:/auth/logout.php");}
        }else{ header("location:/auth/logout.php"); }
    }else{ $stmt->error; $stmt->close();}
}
```

**And at the top of my profile.php page I have the code which checks for a valid session:**

```
<?php
session_start();

include("style/fonts/fonts.html");
include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/Krumo/class.krumo.php");
include_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth/class_loader.php");
krumo($_SESSION);

    $sessCheck = new userFunc;
    if($sessCheck->validSess('bool')){
        $sess = true;
        echo "SESSION IS VALID";
    }
    else{ $sess = false; $_SESSION['msg'] = "You are not logged in, please log in to access your profile.";}
?>
```

Comment: If you provide the image URLs someone will insert them into the question.

Comment: Does this `include("style/fonts/fonts.html");` cause PHP to output something? Do all your session work before outputting anything.

Comment: fonts doesn't cause an output, no, its simply a file which adds in fonts for the site.

Comment: It's an HTML file. How does it not output something unless it's empty? Run this and view source `<?php include("style/fonts/fonts.html"); die;`

Comment: Its only a <link> but i've moved it down, it is after session_start though so I know its not that causing the problem.

Comment: So I guess nobody is really sure then? @Popnoodles

Comment: Moved it to where? After ALL the session work? It is outputting something. If you turn errors on you may see the error Headers Already Sent.

Comment: i think you should also use in each function where you take use of the $_SESSION  add: global $_SESSIONS  no?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem!

The logout.php file headed back to the www. version of the site, whilst the session was running on the non-www. version of the site, Because some links used the "/" to get to the root path and some used the full address, I technically caused two sessions to occur, one that was the previous session that ran on www. and the new session which ran on the non-www.

All of this was cause by some url re-writing in my .HTACCESS

SUCCESS! (for now)